# VS 2019 version 16.8.1 falsely reports that App derives from Application, when it does NOT

Tags: c#, wpf

Today I downloaded both version 16.8, then 16.8.1. I'm working on a team, on a new WPF app, using .NET 4.5.2. Building the app it informed me that the class in App.xaml.cs couldn't derive from `Application`.

> CS0713    Static class 'App' cannot derive from type 'Application'. Static classes must derive from object.

It had been written to derive from `Application`. I changed it as CS0713 said I should. It now derives from `Object`, as that error recommended it should. However, when I build it I am getting an error from the App.g.cs file, saying that it still derives from `Application`?! It does **NOT**!

```
public static partial class App : Object 
{
    private static AppEntities _MainDataContext;
    private static string _Name;
    private static string _Schema;
```

I have cleaned the solution, multiple times, but when I build it again, that error comes back.

I have manually deleted all .g.cs files. But when I build it again, the error comes back.

How do I get this resolved?

Comment: Why is it marked `static`?

Comment: To elaborate on the previous comment: in WPF, the `App` class would not normally be a `static` class. Why is yours? If, as you say, _"It had been written to derive from Application"_, why would you change the declaration to make it static, precluding it inheriting any other type? Your question is very unclear; from everything you've written, you've inexplicably created code that is intentionally invalid, and now are wondering why that invalid code doesn't work. Which is a really odd question to ask.

Comment: @madreflection I do not know why my colleague marked it `static`, other than the fact that he wanted to use properties out of it which were marked `static`. He's out on paternity leave, so I can't talk to him about it until December. I've put it back to a normal class declaration, and made the properties `static` he wanted to use elsewhere in the code. And I made it inherit from Application, instead of Object.

Comment: It's unfortunate that he didn't understand that you can access static members of a class without marking it static. There's no way to have non-static members in a static class, either. It's not like a VB Module, where everything is implicitly Shared.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the C# [language specification](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/language-specification/classes#static-classes) on static classes:

> A static class may not include a class_base specification (Class base specification) and cannot explicitly specify a base class or a list of implemented interfaces. **A static class implicitly inherits from type object.**

Your custom application object, named `App` by default in VS, must be derived from [`Application`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.application?view=net-5.0), which per language specification **cannot** be `static`. It is only created once, acting [as a singleton](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.application?view=net-5.0#remarks).

> Application implements the singleton pattern to provide shared access to its window, property, and resource scope services. Consequently, **only one instance** of the Application class can be created per AppDomain.

You can of course create a static entry point to your application, but that does not involve an `Application` object at all, so you would not create a derived type in the first place.

> A standalone application **does not require** an Application object; it is possible to implement a custom static entry point method (Main) that opens a window without creating an instance of Application. However, XAML browser applications (XBAPs) require an Application object.

In summary, your application type should be declared like this:

```
public partial class App : Application
{
   // ...your application code.
}
```

Comment: Thank  you, thatguy. One of my colleagues changed the App.xaml.cs to be a static class. I think we've been getting away with it because previous versions of Visual Studio weren't as restrictive in enforcing that App had to be in a class and inherit from Application. VS 2019 version 16.8.x is being tougher. I appreciate your giving me the information you did. Armed with that I can helpfully convince my colleague not to do that anymore.

Comment: Previous versions couldn't have been less restrictive. Since it was introduced in C# 2.0, a `static` class is actually an `abstract`+`sealed` class (in its metadata). That means it can't be instantiated (because it's abstract) and it can't be inherited (because it's sealed).

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like App is still declared as Application in the .xaml